# C command line arguments for printing square

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, command-line

This code is supposed to print out a square like this without the blank line between them. I am trying to use the command line argument to determine the size of the square. It seems to just no read in the command line argument and just counts from 1 until I hit CTRL-C to stop it.

012345

123456

234567

345678

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <stdlib.h>                                                              
                                                                             
                                                                             
int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                 
{                                                                                
 int row;                                                                       
 int colm;                                                                      
                                                                             
 // Check for a command line argument.                                          
 if(argc < 2){                                                                  
  printf("usage: box size");                                                   
 }                                                                              
 else{                                                                          
                                                                             
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);                                                       
                                                                             
  for (row = 0; row <= n; row++){                                              
  n = row;                                                                   
  for (colm = 0; colm <= n; colm++){                                         
    printf("%d ",n);                                                         
    n++;                                                                     
  }                                                                          
  printf("\n");                                                              
 }                                                                            
}                                                                              
return 0;                                                                      
}
```

Comment: Please change `if(argc < 1)` to `if(argc < 2)`. The executable name is the first argument `argv[0]`. Also, to printf `n` rows change `for (row = 0; row <= n; row++)` to `for (row = 0; row < n; row++)`.

Comment: I appreciate the advice...it helped me thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `n++;` in the loop `for (colm = 0; colm <= n; colm++){` makes the upperbound escape from being reached and the loop will continue until overflow happens.

What you should do is printing the sum of `row` and `colm` without changing `n`.

```
for (row = 0; row <= n; row++){
  for (colm = 0; colm <= n; colm++){
    printf("%d ",row + colm);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```